# How to get image of Google Hosted Private App?

Tags: android-management-api

I published an private App by using Managed iframe in my EMM console and i got it available under my enterprise successfully.
**Question** : I need to store the published private app image and other details while approving it from managed iframe, is there any way to get an image of private app under enterprise from my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are an EMM approved developer, you can use the [EMM Products API](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/v1/products). It returns links to app icons. If not and you are working on a Java solution, you could try my [java-app-icons](https://github.com/petarov/java-app-icons) library that fetches Play store app icons by package names. The library require Java 11 or upper version.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i will try out this solutions.

Comment: EMM Products API this one provided above is an old API, is there anything similar like this in Android Management API.

Comment: No, the AMAPI's `enterprises.applications.get` call does not support app icons at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your account that has access to the Play Dev Account. You could use this [API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits.images/list) to get the image of your private app.